# bash: find with grep in if always true

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep, find

Ok so this code works

```
if grep -lq something file.txt ; then
```

So why something like this doesnt? what am i doing wrong?

```
if find . -name file.txt -exec grep -lq something {} \;
```

its always true as long as the directory exist.

Comment: Because `find` has exited successfully?

Comment: so what test should i make there? if file doesnt exist its still true

Comment: It depends on what you want to do if the pattern is matched. If it's something simple, you can add another `-exec` after the first one, which will only execute if `grep` is successful.

Comment: I want to check with this find with few more options if that file exist with certain content - do something if not do something else.

Comment: Do you want to determine whether *any* file contains your desired content? Determine whether *every* file contains your desired content? What is the actual desired behavior of this command?

Answer (score 2):

From the [find man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

> Exit Status
>
> find exits with status 0 if all files are processed successfully, greater than 0 if errors occur. This is deliberately a very broad description, but if the return value is non-zero, you should not rely on the correctness of the results of find.

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting back from your command is the exit value of the `find` and not the `grep`. Find almost always returns an exit value of zero as long as the query is good.

I was thinking this might work:

```
find . -name file.txt -print0 | xargs --0 grep -lq something
```

But that will return only the exit status of the last execution of `grep`. If `grep` was executed multiple times, you won't get the intermediate values. However, this probably won't be an issue with your command.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is to check if `find`'s output is empty:

```
output=$( find . -name file.txt -exec grep -lq something {} \; )
if [ -n "$output" ]
then
  # found 
else
  # not found
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach which will short-circuit as soon as a file containing the desired contents is found (presuming that your intent is to look for whether *any* file matches, as opposed to whether *every* file matches):

```
check_for_content() {
  target=$1; shift
  while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
    if grep -lq -e "$target" "$filename"; then
      return 0
    fi
  done < <(find "$@" -print0)
  return 1
}
```

Usage:

```
check_for_content thing-to-look-for -type f -name file.txt
```